# Gradle Daemon doesn't start properly and fills up the whole memory

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

A while ago, I noticed that If I leave my pc open for a bit (Until the gradle daemon terminates timeouts), IntelliJ keeps trying to start a new instance of Gradle. Thus,
I have to restart my whole machine..

Getting Spammed With this:-

[image: Spam Message]

Last gradle process just crashes with the error: `Address already in use: Cannot bind.`

And now gradle is all over my pc:-

[image: Ram Overflow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your network configuration. Such an issue usually occurs when there is firewall/antivirus or sometimes VPN connection may re-configure the network setup on machine. See [case 1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-234314#focus=Comments-27-3973942.0-0) and [case 2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-234314#focus=Comments-27-4001598.0-0).